# Evaluating the result of stanford nlp for sentiment analysis

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to test few sentence using stanford NLP package and want to get sentiment result with it's score.

I tried in couple of ways. In few test I got partial result, like polarity of the text I gave. But not the sentiment score.

This is the command I executed: `H:\Drive E\Stanford\stanfor-corenlp-full-2013~>java -cp "*" -mx1g  edu.stanford. nlp.sentiment.Evaluate edu/stanford/nlp/models/sentiment/sentiment.ser.gz test.txt`

Gives result:

```
EVALUATION SUMMARY
Tested 0 labels
  0 correct
  0 incorrect
  ? accuracy
Tested 0 roots
  0 correct
  0 incorrect
  ? accuracy
Label confusion matrix: rows are gold label, columns predicted label
         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0
Root label confusion matrix: rows are gold label, columns predicted label
         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0
Approximate negative label accuracy: ?
Approximate positive label accuracy: ?
Combined approximate label accuracy: ?
Approximate negative root label accuracy: ?
Approximate positive root label accuracy: ?
Combined approximate root label accuracy: ?
```

`text.txt` contains

This movie doesn't care about cleverness, wit or any other kind of intelligent humor.
Those who find ugly meanings in beautiful things are corrupt without being charming.
There are slow and repetitive parts, but it has just enough spice to keep it interesting.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to get sentiment scores use this command -

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.3.1.jar:stanford-corenlp-3.3.1-models.jar:xom.jar:joda-time.jar:jollyday.jar:ejml-0.23.jar -Xmx3g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,parse,pos,sentiment -file input.txt
```

this will generate a xml file with name input.txt.xml, with sentiment score like this -

```
<sentence id="1" sentimentValue="1" sentiment="Negative">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't evaluate text file. You have to evaluate treebank.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, but it does technically address the problem. Could you elaborate (how exactly to do so for example)?